# Php Object oriented, Function calling

Tags: php, function, object, call

This is my php page **persona.php**:

```
<?php
 class persona {
 private $name;
 public function __construct($n){
    $this->name=$n;
 }
 public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
}

public function changeName($utente1,$utente2){
    $temp=$utente1->name;
    $utente1->name=$utente2->name;
    $utente2->name=$temp;

    }
}
?>
```

The class `persona` is simple and just shows the constructor and a function that change two users name if called.

This is **index.php**:

```
<?php
require_once "persona.php" ;
    $utente1 = new persona("Marcello");
    print "First user: <b>". $utente1->getName()."</b><br><br>";
    $utente2 = new persona("Sofia");
    print "Second user: <b>". $utente2->getName()."</b><br>";
    changename($utente1,$utente2);
    print " Test after name changes: first user". $utente1->getName()."</b> second user". $utente2->getName();
?>
```

What I do not understand is how to call the `changeName` function from here.

Comment: So you know how to call `getName` but cannot call `changeName()` ?

Comment: $utente1->changename($utente1,$utente2);

Answer (score 2):

I can understand where the confusion arises from...I think you are unsure if you should call `changename` on `$utente1` or `$utente2`. Technically you can call it from either objects because they are both instances of `Persona`

But for clarity (and sanity), I would recommend converting the `changeName` function to a `static function` in its declaration:

`public static function changeName($utente1,$utente2){`

and then in your index.php you can call it as:

`Persona::changename($utente1,$utente2);`

From an architecture stamp point, this will help provide a better sense that the function is tied to the class of Persona, and objects can change swap names using that class function, as opposed to making it an instance function and then having any object execute it.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case you can call it as:

```
$utente1->changename($utente1,$utente2);
or
$utente2->changename($utente1,$utente2);
```

It doesn't matter which. As the method itself doesn't work with the classes properties (but only with the method parameters), you can call it from any object that exist.

But better (best practice, and better by design) is to develop a static method, as Raidenace already said, and call it like:

```
Persona::changename($utente1,$utente2);
```

Comment: Thx very much to both of you :) I'm sorry if the question seemed to be a dumb one but even if I am quite good at php programming and java it is the first time I have tried to approach php OO. Thank you again!