# How do i call function in php

Tags: php, oop

I have this simple php code.I am basically new with core php and i've used some frameworks before where the function is called through the url.

```
<?php
class calculation
{
    public $x=5; $y=6;
    public function getSum()
    {
        $z=$x+$y;
        print_r($z);
     }
}
```

How can i call `getSum()` function? I've tried with:

```
int main()
{
   calcuation c1;
   c1.getSum();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: $obj = new calculation();
$obj->getSum();

Comment: you are not able this       $z=$x+$y; inside function

Comment: Get a good PHP book or read some up to date PHP tutorials online. PHP is different from C++.

Comment: @MdHasiburRahaman why  `$z=$x+$y;` cannot be done inside function.

Comment: you not define $x and $y inside this function , if you want to member variable you have to use $this->x

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php Object oriented, Function calling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468632/php-object-oriented-function-calling)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is not PHP code.

To call a method from an instance of object you have to do it like this :

```
$c1 = new calculation();
$c1->getSum();
```

See [PHP OOP basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) to learn more.

Be aware that your `calculation` class is wrong. To access class property, you have to use `$this->` like this :

```
<?php
class calculation
{
    public $x=5; 
    public $y=6;

    public function getSum()
    {
        $z= $this->x + $this->y;
        //return $z; //would be a better way to do calculation
        print_r($z);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class calculation
{
    public $x=5, $y=6;
    public function getSum()
    {
        $z=$this->x + $this->y;
        print_r($z);
     }
}
```

Call This Function

```
$obj = new calculation();
$obj->getSum()
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add something. If you creating the calculator application  it's a good idea make  getSum() function as  static and pass the params to it.

```
<?php
     class calculation
        {
            public static function getSum(x,y)
            {
                return x+y;
            }
        }

        echo calculation::getSum(1,1);
```

Also it's a good idea to return the value from the function and not to print it out from inside.

This rule save a lot of headache in a case of complicated application.

By the way:

```
int main(){
.....
}
```

it could be nice, but PHP itself encapsulate this functionality, so you just scripting the "body"